# How to get the size of browsing window in width and height using ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I want retrieve the width and height of browser in pixel(px) using ruby code. I don't have any idea how to do this.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of Javascript you can calculate the width and height of browser and pass this info to server using AJAX .

Else not possible by ruby code .

EDITED :

If you are working on rails app than you can do it like :

To get the browser dimension use the link :
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

And if you using jQuery then use below function to get the height and width of window .

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

And use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) feature to pass this dimension to your action .

Comment: Hey Vik can you help me with javascript, because i don't know how to include javascript code in simple rb file, and where to include

Comment: Jeet, you can not include javascript code into ruby files as I and Xdazz mentioned . I have edited my answer, Please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Server side language can't do that, you should use javascript to do such thing.